# Is it possible to hack WPS PIN of routers that lockout exponentially after failed tries?

Tags: network, wifi, wireless, kali-linux, wps

I have been interested in Wireless hacking lately, and I can do dictionary attacks, and some other type of attacks. Though, I wanted to hack my ASUS RT-N12D1 router's WPS PIN. ASUS doesn't alllow to change the WPS PIN to a custom value and it ships with prespecified WPS PIN.

Anyway, I enabled WPS, and tried to hack it using `wifite`, `reaver`, and `bully`, but I just wasn't successful with any of these tools. Because, the router is a bit new, and as long as I know new routers have some protections against known WPS attacks, such as locking the WPS after a few failed attempts, and after more failed attempts the lockdown time increases exponentially I guess, until it is completely locked and you need to manually switch it off/on.

Are there any known working methods in order to hack WPS PIN of a router that locks WPS after a few attempts?

Comment: Did you try to change your MAC address every time you get locked out?

Comment: @BubbleHacker It would be a smart idea if the script would automatically do that, unless there's an option already?

Comment: Take a look at this project: https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/reaver-wps/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your AP is able to filter out the MAC address and block it after an x amount of requests. What you need to do is to change the MAC address every x requests so the router won't be able to lock you out.

Use reaver mac address changer: `Reaver -i mon0 -c x -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -vv --mac=vv:vv:vv:vv:vv:vv`

**Warning**: This might crash your router do to an overload of requests...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very automatic tool, cause I will need to call reaver each time I change the MAC. I tried the above link that you have, but it basically does only EAPOL calls.

Comment: Changing the mac does not work for all APs. From experience most disable WPS for any MAC during the lockout period